# Se distancia mucho el 'menu contextual' del boton

Tags: css

Estoy utilizando las librerias: bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js y jquery.min.js para aplicar estilos css a mi website.

El funcionamiento es correcto, el problema lo tengo en el menu contextual, el cual me aparece muy por encima del boton el cual hago click.

¿A que parametro tengo que ir para modificar la posicion del menu contextual?

Tengo:

```
<div class="dropdown d-flex">
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary dropdown-toggle mb-1 w-100 text-left'.$selected.'" type="button" id="Menu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i> Facebook
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Menu1">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="web1">uno</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="web2">dos</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="web3">tres</a>
</div>
```

[image: ejemplo-menu-imagen]

Comment: Hola, agrega el código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Ya agregue el codigo, el resto son las librerias que he mencionado.

Comment: Intenta agregandole `position: relative` al `<div class="dropdown d-flex">`

Comment: Estoy en ello, pero no logro que me funcione, y puse 'position: relative'. La modificacion tengo que hacerla en el archivo: bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Estoy mirando --> data-toggle="dropdown"